# I have a few questions about Python string manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Can any one please explain me why this prints none for the first statement where it says `"university"`? The second command prints index(-5) and index(3) which is `cd` but the first one gives me back nothing.

```py
x = "university"
print(x[-5:4])
x = "abcdefg"
print(x[-5:4])
```

Comment: because there is no array of letters starting at  5(10-5) and ending at 4. That is impossible.

Comment: What are you expecting, and what are the (other) questions?

Answer (score 0):

You print out *slices* of strings which start at index `-5` and end at index `4`. [*Slicing*](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) differs from single-element access (`x[i]`) not only in one or more colons (`:`) being involved, but in so far as you ***specify a range*** with a ***start*** index and an ***end*** index (*start* is inclusive whereas *end* isn't). The range `[-5:4]` is empty for `"university"` and contains two elements for `"abcdefg"`.

See for illustration the content of the strings in relation to indices:

```
0  1  2  3 ]4
u  n  i  v  e  r  s  i  t  y
             [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

```
0  1  2  3 ]4
a  b  c  d  e  f  g
    [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

... which make it obvious that that the substring for `university` must be empty.

What you, probably, might be expecting is a 4-character substring beginning at index `-5` which can be achieved by `x[-5,-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the string `"university"` the index `-5` is `'e'` but index `4` is `'r'`.
If you print the values

```py
x = "university"
print(x[-5:])
print(x[:4])
```

You get

```
rsity
univ
```

It's because the indexes aren't on the letters, but between the letters. so you get
"unive||rsity" with | being an index.

Answer (score 0):

In print(x[-5:4]) function, the first index -5  indicate "r" and  second index 4 indicate "e" so first index was greater than the second index at the position of string.

However, in case of x= "university", the starting index are larger in position,
so there is no overlapping section, so no value is output.

If you fix it with print(x[-9:4]) it will out put  'niv'.

I hope that it will help you.

thanks

Comment: Thank You, I think  I got it now when we slice starting from negative index to positive, it prints the intersection that they cross each other. I appreciate all your responses. In the case of university staring from -5 backward and starting from 0 going forward. They don't cross each other. it basically prints the intersection.